# How to fit a model to minimize a function

Tags: regression

[
\begin{aligned}
f\left(x, y, x_{i}, y_{i}\right)=& \psi_{i} \times x+\phi_{i} \times y \\
&+\partial_{i} \sqrt{\left(x-x_{i}\right)^{2}+(y-y)^{2}} - s_i
\end{aligned}
]

My aim to minimize this. This is kind of model fitting. How to do this using python? Moreover

this will lead to $$\min _{x, y} \sum_{i} f_{i}\left(x, y, x_{i}, y_{i}\right)^{2}$$

How to type all of this latex in Python.

I have tried [this](https://github.com/OrangeX4/latex2sympy) but did not work.

Comment: There are probably constraints which are missing about the expression? At least it's trivial to set the paramters to zero. In general this would be an optimization problem, there's no 'model to fit' normally. A genetic algorithm is good approach for these. The 2nd question is completely different: do you want to use this library for symbolic computation??

Comment: Yes. \begin{aligned}
&\psi_{i}=\left(x_{i}-x_{1}\right) \quad s_{i}=k_{l}-k_{i}-\frac{\partial}{2} \\
&\phi_{i}=\left(y_{i}-y_{1}\right) \\
&\partial_{i}=-2 c\left(d_{i}-d_{1}\right)
\end{aligned} these are known to me and  $i$ > 1

Comment: So weights is c. The variables are Xi , yi , ki , di . Constants are x1 y1 d1 k1 . 
Use gradient descent to minimize loss . You need to minimize wrt c only.